# Object File Linkage Order After Compiling Multiple .cpp files in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linkage

When compiling multiple .cpp files how Visual Studio knows the linkage order of the .cpp files? Is it assumed that main.cpp is always linked last due to the dependencies from other .cpp files? I remember when using Linux back in grad school the linkage order of the .o files was very important.

Comment: MSVC does multi-pass linking so there is usually no issues.  IIRC GCC does single-pass and is therefore order dependent.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the order would matter, for any reasonable build system. It is not unusual for two source files to call each other's functions; I haven't met a C++ implementation unable to build a program containing such a pair of source files.